# Generating combinations of two strings using Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation, combinations, permutation

I have a string str1 = "ABC" and I need to insert 0 to len(str1) number of "x"s in the string str1 except at the last position.

So in the above example, I want a resultant list with 0 to 2 "x"s placed before or inside the string which looks like

```
["ABC",
 "xABC",
 "AxBC",
 "ABxC",
 "xxABC",
 "xAxBC",
 "xABxC",
 "AxxBC",
 "AxBxC",
 "ABxxC"]
```

I tried some code which is as follows (I do realize that I have missed out few combinations in this):

```
>>> for i in range(1, len(str1)):
...     for k in range(len(str1)):
...         str1[:k]+"x"*i+str1[k:]
... 
'xABC'
'AxBC'
'ABxC'
'xxABC'
'AxxBC'
'ABxxC'
>>>
```

I am not really sure about how to approach the other case with inter-leavings between the two for e.g. xAxBC etc

What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find the permutations of string? python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140144/how-to-find-the-permutations-of-string-python)

Comment: @alko thanks for pointing that out. however the question is not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) to get indexes to insert `x`s.:

```
import itertools

str1 = "ABC"
lst = list(str1)
for n in range(len(str1)):
    for idxs in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(str1)), n):
        xs = lst[:]
        for i in reversed(idxs): # Use reversed, otherwise index become invald
            xs.insert(i, 'x')
        print(''.join(xs))
```

output:

```
ABC
xABC
AxBC
ABxC
xxABC
xAxBC
xABxC
AxxBC
AxBxC
ABxxC
```

Comment: wow, you are too fast, it took me this long just to find what it's called. Here's the reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! While this seems to work fine to strings of length upto 10-15, it becomes excruciatingly slow for larger numbers. Is there anything that can be done to speed it up? Like memoization for example? 

I was trying something on the lines that (xABC, AxBC, ABxC) are repeated again when x is added at the beginning like xxABC, xAxBC, xABxC.